Asset Library not showing new assets
I'm pretty new to Blender, so I'm not sure if I am missing something. I purchased some assets from users and followed their tutorials on how to use the assets. Example: I downloaded the .blender file and added it to the Asset Library. However, when I open my Asset Library, the assets do not appear. Anybody know what the hell is going on? Very frustrating. emphasized text

what happens if you click on all?

Make sure you don't have anything typed in the search bar in the top right of the asset browser editor. Also have you actually marked the objects as assets in the blend file ?

Nothing appears if I click on all. How do I mark the objects as assets if I just downloaded them?
